# Read request payload in Go?

Tags: http, post, go, multipart

I'm using a file uploader and need details from the request payload to crop it.

```
func Upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    reader, err := r.MultipartReader()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    //copy each part to destination.
    for {
        part, err := reader.NextPart()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if part.FormName() == "avatar_data"{
           // Read the content in "avatar_data" how?
        }
        if part.FileName() == "" {
            continue
        }
        dst, err := os.Create("/Users/macadmin/test/" + part.FileName())
        defer dst.Close()
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        if _, err := io.Copy(dst, part); err != nil {

            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    }
    img, _ := imaging.Open("/Users/macadmin/test/cry3.jpg")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    rect := image.Rect(0, 0, 200, 500)
    // rect := image.Rectangle{20,20}
    dst := imaging.Crop(img, rect)
    err = imaging.Save(dst, "/Users/macadmin/test/cry4.jpg")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    //display success message.
}
```

I don't have 10 rep to post the image of the POST request, but it has

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar_data"

{"x":528,"y":108,"height":864,"width":864}
```

So from avatar_data I need the `x`, `y`, `height`, and `width`. I know I'll have to marshal the JSON but I'm not sure how to get to that point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`multipart.Part`](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Part) implements the `io.Reader` interface.

```
if part.FormName() == "avatar_data" {
    j, err := ioutil.ReadAll(part)
    if err != nil {
        //do something
    }
    //j == []byte(`{"x":528,"y":108,"height":864,"width":864}`), do something with it.
}
```