# Go, extract form values from multipart POST

Tags: go, multipartform-data

I've been struggle a lot with extracting form values from a multipart request form in Go. The form contains x number of key : values and also a file.

The parts do exist in the BODY when I print the whole body.

**Alternative 1:**

```
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseMultipartForm(0)

    fmt.Println(r.FormValue("key"))
}
```

This returns only empty values.

**Alternative 2:**

My second approach was to do something like this with MultipartReader():

[Read request payload in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061784/read-request-payload-in-go)

However, this give me "unexpected EOF" before getting the last value with FormValue(). It does however print 9/10 values.

Can someone with more experience with Go give some hints how to fix this? And yes, I think I've searched the whole net for a solution now. Nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Alternative #1 is correct.  What is the error return from r.ParseMulipartForm?

Comment: As noted your example looks fine. Have you confirmed that the request body has any data? I would recommend printing the POST body and comparing that output to what you're expecting to parse out of the form.

Comment: Yes, I've already verified that I get the values when I print the POST body.

The error I get from .ParseMultipartForm: multipart: NextPart: EOF

Comment: It looks like the form is incomplete.  What are you using to generate the form?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I had some error in the code that created the form (in Go). Thanks! Alternative #1 is correct.